# Extract any possible combination of two strings

Tags: python

Giving these two strings `x = 'abc'  y = 'dc';`

How can I get this output -> `set()={'ac', 'ab', 'cd', 'ad', 'cb', 'bd'}`

Getting `ab` from `x` then `ac` from `x` then `ad` from `x and y` ...

If it is possible using only `set` functions without additional libraries.

I tried this :

```
    X = set()
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        X.add(i+j)
print(X)
```

Comment: You can try `itertools.product` from the standard library. It's not external, it comes with python

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, your output should be `{'cc', 'cb', 'bd', 'db', 'ac', 'bb', 'cd', 'aa', 'dd', 'bc', 'ad', 'da', 'dc', 'ca'}` because you take all combination in `x` with `x`, `y` with `y`, `x` with `y` and `y` with `x`. Am I right?

Comment: I might be missing something, but can you take `set(x+y)` and list all the pairs from it?

Comment: @mousetail :  I'm trying to solve it without using itertools.

Comment: @Raida : yes but 'da' and 'ad' , 'bc' and 'cb' ...  in my case are same so only one of them should be used.

Comment: Ok so you need all combination without their "mirror"?

Comment: @Raida : yes exactly . sorry for not mentioning it above.

Comment: And duplicates like `aa`, `dd`, etc must not be present too?

Comment: @Raida yes , same output as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code :

```py
def get_combinations(x, y):
    r = set()

    def add(s):
        if s[::-1] not in r and s[0] != s[1]:
            r.add(s)

    c = set(x + y)
    for i in c:
        for j in c:
            if i <= j:
                add(i + j)

    return r
```

The inner `add` function check that the mirror is not present and the two letters are different.

`c` is used to iterate over all possibilities.

The condition `i <= j` is used to sort the mirrors option by alphabetical order.

The following assertion is verified (note that I changed your `"cb"` by `"bc"` because of the alphabetical order) :

```py
x = "abc"
y = "dc"
assert get_combinations(x, y) == {"ac", "ab", "cd", "ad", "bc", "bd"}
```